# XML::Twig is ignoring some elements?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, xml-twig

Part of the XML looks like this:

```
<ipcEntry kind="1" symbol="A01B0013080000" ipcLevel="A" entryType="K" lang="EN" nocore="yes">
    <textBody>
        <title>
            <titlePart>
                <text>for working subsoil</text>
            </titlePart>
        </title>
    </textBody>
    <ipcEntry kind="2" symbol="A01B0013100000" ipcLevel="A" entryType="K" lang="EN" nocore="yes">
        <textBody>
            <title>
                <titlePart>
                    <text>Special implements for lifting subsoil layers</text>
                </titlePart>
            </title>
        </textBody>
        <ipcEntry kind="3" symbol="A01B0013120000" ipcLevel="A" entryType="K" lang="EN" nocore="yes">
            <textBody>
                <title>
                    <titlePart>
                        <text>Means for distributing the layers on the surface</text>
                    </titlePart>
                </title>
            </textBody>
        </ipcEntry>
    </ipcEntry>
</ipcEntry>
```

My Code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

my $twig_handlers = { 'ipcEntry' =>  \&ipcEntrySub };

my $file = 'A01B.xml';
my $twig= new XML::Twig( twig_handlers => $twig_handlers );
$twig->parsefile($file);
#$twig->print;




sub ipcEntrySub {

   my ($twig_obj, $element) = @_;

  print $element->{'att'}->{'symbol'} . "\n";
 print "Kind: $element->{'att'}->{'kind'}\n";
 print $element->text . "\n";
 print "###########################################\n";


    $twig_obj->purge;

}
```

seems like I cant get the text: `<text>Special implements for lifting subsoil layers</text>`
I guess its because `<ipcEntry kind="2" symbol="A01B0013100000" ipcLevel="A" entryType="K" lang="EN" nocore="yes">` has another sub ipcEntry.

I can get `<text>Means for distributing the layers on the surface</text>`.

what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to be?

Comment: basically, to print all the <text> elements in there, alongside with the attributes of each <ipcEntry>

Comment: When you purge, you loose all the elements before the current one. You just keep the parents of the element, empty, ie you can still access their attributes, but all their content is lost. So indeed delete is what you want here.

Comment: +1 mirod, I think your comment is much clearer than my answer.  It would be great if you could include the above comment in the XML::Twig Perl documentation.  I was certainly puzzled, as to how I could access the attributes, but not the content after purging an element.  Also huge thanks for the awesome XML::Twig.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the XML::Twig documentation:

> flush This method should NOT be used,
> always flush the twig, not an element.
>
> purge Does the same as a "flush"
> except it does not print the twig. It
> just deletes all elements that have
> been completely parsed so far.

Replacing the purge function, with the delete function prints the text of all ipcEntry elements in reverse order ie. starting with the innermost ipcEntry element.

```
sub ipcEntrySub {
  my ($twig_obj, $element) = @_;

  print $element->{'att'}->{'symbol'} . "\n";
  print "Kind: $element->{'att'}->{'kind'}\n";
  print $element->text . "\n";

  $element->delete;
}
```

Comment: The XML is appx 8GB in size, if I will not purge it every time, my memory will fill up, isnt it? or most probably I dont get the idea behind that 'purge' sub.

Comment: Please excuse my earlier answer which was incorrect.  You certainly should use the "delete" function to cut the ELEMENT (instead of using the "purge" function) to free memory.  Hope this helps.